# Birthday form using HTML/PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm making a registration form which will have the user put in his birthday.
The problem is when it comes to February and months who do not end in 31. The user is able to put something like 31 February or 31 April. Is there any practical way to display just 28 when February is selected? (aside from using Ajax)

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="registration.php" method="post">

<p><u>Select table</u></p>

<p>Select date:</p>
<select name="day">
<?php
for($i=1;$i<=31;$i++)
{
    echo '<option value='.$i.'>'.$i.'</option>';
}


<select name="month">
<option value="January">January</option>
<option value="February">February</option>
<option value="Mars">Mars</option>
<option value="April">April</option>
<option value="May">May</option>
<option value="June">June</option>
<option value="July">July</option>
<option value="September">September</option>
<option value="October">October</option>
<option value="November">November</option>
<option value="December">December</option>
</select>

<select name="year">
<?php
for($i=2011;$i<=2015;$i++)
{
    echo '<option value='.$i.'>'.$i.'</option>';
}

?>
</select>
<br/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'd recommend look for a javascript/jquery control that someone else have already written. There no point reinventing the wheel.

Comment: dropdowns for date components are highly annoying. I actively hate sites that force you to scroll through a stupid 2line high dropdown to find a birthyear or whatever.

Comment: Marc B, i know what you mean, but on desktop computers, you can just type the year on keyboard, the dropdown will jump to the year you typed.

On mobile i actually think dropdowns are better than textinput cause they are so easy to scroll with swipe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use JavaScript to restrict the dropdown to 28, 30, or 31 days based on the month. This does not require you to use AJAX.

Comment: How exactly can I change the values of the dropdown list if the html is static?

Comment: With JavaScript, the HTML is not static. For example, using JavaScript and jQuery you can wire up an event when the month changes: `$('select[name="month"]').change(function(){ ... Change the HTML for days here ... });`

Comment: The problem is I don't have a lot of experience with JavaScript.I'd have to remove the PHP part and rewrite it in JavaScript right?

Comment: Not necessarily: the two complement each other. PHP code runs on the server, and JavaScript code runs in the browser. You could still keep what you are doing in PHP and just wire up a change event in JavaScript for when the month changes.

Comment: *facepalm* ok. I'll try it out :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that.

Most people are most comfortable typing their birthday out in full. The `<option>/<select>` bit is *really* unnecessary.

If you don't have access to a good date guesser server side (odds are you do), break it into three separate fields, but usually, that's not even necessary.

Just give them a single field that can comfortably fit 10 digits, and if the date is ambiguous when you receive it, ask the user if you guessed right.

Comment: This is what I'm doing right now. But I don't feel comfortable with it.

Comment: @patokun: Why is it that you don't feel comfortable with it?

Comment: It will make the user have to check if the current month is 30/31. It's a small thing I know, but it's the little things that count :D 
edit: this issue is regarding another date selection I have on the site. 2 birds in 1 stone :)

Comment: @patokun: If you are asking the user for a date, it stands to reason that you can expect them to know that date. Most people I know have very few problems remembering what months have how many days, and if asked for a specific date, the issue of how many days are in a month rarely enters into it at all.

Answer (score 1):

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Use this and all your date problems are solved forever.

Comment: The jQuery UI datepicker is great, but it's a poor choice for a birthday picker, https://github.com/abecoffman/birthdaypicker
is a better option.

Comment: The css was messed up for me when I tried this, there was no backdrop for the calendar popup and the text was overlapping.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
Date Of Birth:
<select name="month" onChange="changeDate(this.options[selectedIndex].value);">
<option value="na">Month</option>
<option value="1">January</option>
<option value="2">February</option>
<option value="3">March</option>
<option value="4">April</option>
<option value="5">May</option>
<option value="6">June</option>
<option value="7">July</option>
<option value="8">August</option>
<option value="9">September</option>
<option value="10">October</option>
<option value="11">November</option>
<option value="12">December</option>
</select>
<select name="day" id="day">
<option value="na">Day</option>
</select>
<select name="year" id="year">
<option value="na">Year</option>
</select>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function changeDate(i){
var e = document.getElementById('day');
while(e.length>0)
e.remove(e.length-1);
var j=-1;
if(i=="na")
k=0;
else if(i==2)
k=28;
else if(i==4||i==6||i==9||i==11)
k=30;
else
k=31;
while(j++<k){
var s=document.createElement('option');
var e=document.getElementById('day');
if(j==0){
s.text="Day";
s.value="na";
try{
e.add(s,null);}
catch(ex){
e.add(s);}}
else{
s.text=j;
s.value=j;
try{
e.add(s,null);}
catch(ex){
e.add(s);}}}}
y = 1993;
while (y-->1940){
var s = document.createElement('option');
var e = document.getElementById('year');
s.text=y;
s.value=y;
try{
e.add(s,null);}
catch(ex){
e.add(s);}}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```