# Regular expression that validate future date

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on mvc 4 with asp.net, i want to validate date of birth so user cannot select future date, how i can do that?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#DOB").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "m/d/yy",
        });
    });
</script>
@Html.TextBox("DOB", Model.DOB.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), new { @class = "cssClass" })
```

i don't want server side validation i want to validate on client side. can i validate it with regular expression?

**Solution:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#DOB").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "m/d/yy",
        }).change(function () {
            var date = new Date($("#DOB").val());
            var now = new Date();
            if (date > now) {
                alert("Please enter valid date.");
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: If you _only_ validate on the client side then how are you really validating the input? This can be circumvented. And your server-side validation for future dates is as simple as a _greater/smaller than_ comparison.

Comment: datepicker.Date < DateTime.Now or some such, regex is for strings

Comment: @Thomas: i edited the question with cs file code to show how i am validating in mvc, how i can add more validation for future date?

Comment: @Tony Hopkinson: on which datepicker i should write this code. onchange event?

Comment: @GrantThomas: Maybe it's only usability-oriented validation as opposed to a security-related validation. Maybe also the fact that today on a client may not be the same as today on the server (due to time zones) makes server-side validation that matches client-side validation a bit tricky. (Just making assumptions here of course!)

Comment: @Clafou between being born and being able to read and enter a web form, about three years will have passed at least. When your server date is three years behind, you have other problems.

Comment: @Clafou We're talking dates of birth here, not timezones, offsets and synchronicity.

Comment: @CodeCaster Not necessarily--maybe he's recording the date of birth of a newborn child. It could be today, and the server may see today as a different date than the user's browser. I don't know the OP at all but by sheer coincidence I happen to work on a pediatric application where a similar problem applies.

Answer (score 0):

Make 3 fields for day, month and year, like almost any site online.
Fill the fields up with values.
Then you can populate the year dropdown according to your wishes.
And you can simply use the change event to validate the other fields.
Plus you can simply use day + month + year, make a date value, and compare with your_date <= new date() 
Otherwise, you will have to worry about all the different dateformats a string can have, which makes it impossible to validate it.

See here:
[Birthday form using HTML/PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961007/birthday-form-using-html-php)

Something like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">

<head>

    <title>Hello</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">


        function isLeapYear(iYear)
        {
            return (new Date(iYear, 1, 29).getMonth() == 1);
        }

        function getMonthLength(month, year)
        {
            month = month - 1;

            var monthStart = new Date(year, month, 1);
            var monthEnd = new Date(year, month + 1, 1);
            var monthLength = (monthEnd - monthStart) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);

            return monthLength;
        }


        function PopulateDayDropdown(iMonth, iYear)
        {
            for (i = 1; i < getMonthLength(iMonth, iYear) + 1; i++)
            {
                $('<option/>').val(i).html(i).appendTo('#selDay');
            }


        }

        function PopulateMonthDropdown()
        {

            var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];



            for (i = 0; i < months.length; i++)
            {
                $('<option/>').val(i + 1).html(months[i]).appendTo('#selMonth');
            }

        }


        function PopulateYearDropdown()
        {

            var iCurYear = new Date().getFullYear();

            for (i = iCurYear - 100; i <= iCurYear; i++)
            {
                $('<option/>').val(i).html(i).appendTo('#selYear');
            }

            //$('select option[value="' + iCurYear + '"]').html();
            $('#selYear option[value="' + iCurYear + '"]').attr("selected", "selected")

        }



        $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            // Handler for .ready() called.
            PopulateDayDropdown(1, new Date().getFullYear());
            PopulateMonthDropdown();
            PopulateYearDropdown();



            //$('select[name="month"]').change(function()
            $('select').change(function ()
            {
                //alert("2012 leap year? " + isLeapYear(2012) + "\n" + "2013 leap year? " + );

                var iDay = $("#selDay").val();
                var iMonth = $("#selMonth").val();
                var iYear = $("#selYear").val();

                if (this.id == "selMonth" || this.id == "selYear")
                {
                    $('#selDay').empty();
                    PopulateDayDropdown(iMonth, iYear);
                    $('#selDay option[value="' + iDay + '"]').attr("selected", "selected")
                }


                if (iDay > getMonthLength(iMonth, iYear))
                {
                    var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
                    alert("There is no " + iDay + "th " + months[iMonth - 1] + ".");

                }



                var d = new Date(iYear, iMonth - 1, iDay, 0, 0, 0, 0);


                if (d > new Date())
                {
                    $('#selDay option[value="' + 1 + '"]').attr("selected", "selected")
                    $('#selMonth option[value="' + 1 + '"]').attr("selected", "selected")
                    alert("Future dates are not allowed (values have been reset to January 1st).");
                    return;
                }


                alert("New date of birth: " + d);

            });


        });

    </script>


</head>


<body>


<form action="registration.php" method="post">

    <p>Select date:</p>


    <select id="selDay" name="day">
    </select>



    <select id="selMonth" name="month">
    <!--
    <option value="January">January</option>
    <option value="February">February</option>
    <option value="Mars">Mars</option>
    <option value="April">April</option>
    <option value="May">May</option>
    <option value="June">June</option>
    <option value="July">July</option>
    <option value="September">September</option>
    <option value="October">October</option>
    <option value="November">November</option>
    <option value="December">December</option>
    -->
    </select>

    <select id="selYear" name="year">

    </select>

    <br/><br/>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>

</body>
</html>
```